# Incorrect GL_VENDOR and GL_RENDERER in Chromium build

Tags: macos, opengl, chromium, macos-catalina, angle

I'm building a Chromium project under macOS Catalina (10.15.7) following the instructions https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/mac_build_instructions.md.
The compilation is successful, but the resulting binary has problems with hardware acceleration. Some pages are rendered by the browser with strange artifacts (black rectangles in different places of the web pages).

**Output chrome://gpu**

```
Driver vendor ANGLE
Driver version 2.1.14218
Pixel shader version 1.00
Vertex shader version 1.00
Max. MSAA samples 4
GL_VENDOR Google Inc.
GL_RENDER ANGLE (ATI Technologies Inc., AMD Radeon Pro 570 OpenGL Engine, OpenGL 4.1 core)
GL_VERSION OpenGL ES 2.0.0 (ANGLE 2.1.14218 git hash: f9e59ad07855)
```

But the Chromium binary downloaded from here https://chromium.woolyss.com/ doesn't have these problems with page rendering and hardware acceleration.

**Downloaded Chromium output chrome://gpu**

```
Driver vendor ATI
Driver version 3.10.19
Pixel shader version 4.10
Vertex shader version 4.10
Max. MSAA samples 8
GL_VENDOR ATI Technologies Inc.
GL_RENDERER AMD Radeon Pro 570 OpenGL Engine
GL_VERSION 4.1 ATI-3.10.19
```

The versions of Chromium are absolutely identical. For some reason my build chooses ANGLE as GL_RENDERER instead of native ATI driver.

I use the following args.gn to build:

```
ffmpeg_branding="Chrome"
is_official_build=true
proprietary_codecs=true
is_component_build=false
enable_stripping=true
is_debug=false
enable_nacl=false
blink_symbol_level=0
strip_absolute_paths_from_debug_symbols=true
symbol_level=0
dcheck_always_on=false
enable_plugins=true
enable_pdf=true
```

If anyone has encountered a similar problem, which way to look to fix this?

Comment: Better post this issue in this official Chromium graphics dev group: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!forum/graphics-dev Also you should specify what version of Chromium you are compiling

Comment: Also if you have found a solution from Chromium developers then please link that post here, so that it will be helpful to others too